# Run function every time animation repeats

Tags: gsap

Here's a script that animates a bouncing square:

http://jsfiddle.net/YH9nM/18/

```
var count = 1,
       tM = new TimelineLite(),
       element = $('#boxy');

function log(){
    console.log('just bounced');
    element.html('I\'ve bounced: ' + count + ' times!');
    count++;
}

tM.from( element, 2, { top:'-=60px', ease: Linear.easeNone, repeat: -1, onRepeat: log() }, 0 );
```

However, that `onRepeat` option is not behaving as I'd expect. Rather than triggering the log function every time the animation repeats, it runs it once when the animation starts the first time.

It's behaving exactly as the `onStart` option would. Why is this happening? How can I make the div count how many times it's bounced ad infinitum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the `log` function when you define your tween, by using `log()`, and are assigning the return value of `log` to `onRepeat` (which is `undefined` since you don't return anything). You want the `onRepeat` var to be assigned to the `log` function

change

```
onRepeat: log()
```

to

```
onRepeat: log
```

You can see this in action [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/YH9nM/21/)

Comment: Ah okay, but what should you do if you want to pass an argument to your log function?

Comment: you can define a function that calls log `onRepeat: function(){ log(args...); }`. Greensock also allows you to define `onRepeatParams ` an array which gets passed to `onRepeat` http://api.greensock.com/js/

Comment: Thanks very much, just worked it out the second you commented haha

Answer (score 0):

Patrick did actually answer the question, but here's what you want to do if you wish to pass parameters to a function you wish to run onRepeat:

```
onRepeatParams: ['as','many','parameters','as',1,true,'ly','wants'];
```

I also believe the most efficient way to access the element the timeline is applied to is through using the self keyword like this:

```
onRepeatParams: ["{self}"];
```

and then in the function doing this:

```
$(element.target).html('I\'ve bounced: ' + count + ' times!');
```

Here's what I mean in context:

```
var count = 1,
       tM = new TimelineLite(),
       element = $('#boxy');

function log(element){
    console.log('just bounced');
    $(element.target).html('I\'ve bounced: ' + count + ' times!');
    count++;
}

tM.from( element, 2, { top:'-=60px', ease: Linear.easeNone, repeat: -1, onRepeat: log, onRepeatParams: ["{self}"] }, 0 );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YH9nM/23/